# Do I have to create one page for each blog post?

Tags: database, url, blogs

I am creating a blog from scratch using database. I know that I can easily retrieve information from the database if I include the primary key in the url like this:

```
www.url.com/entry?id=1
```

In this case, returning information stored with the primary key of 1. Is it possible for me to retrieve these information as well but without the 'entry?id='?

What I am trying to achieve is to extract the same information but having the url be something like

```
www.url.com/this-is-my-first-entry
```

Is there any way to do it? Or do I have to create a page with 'this-is-my-first-entry' as it's file name? If so, is there a way to have my website automatically create pages for each new entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't have to create a page per each url.

Essentially, `/entry?id=1` and `/this-is-my-first-entry` are **the same** to the web server. It's just a path, the server doesn't care how it will be handled.

It is your code that must handle this (or, rather, rules for routing component of your framework of choice).

In rails, for example, this is a no-brainer. Here's the routing rule.

```
get '/:page' => 'pages#show'
```

If you have this rule, you now can request page with any name, `/this-is-my-first-page`, `/hello-world` or `/you-wont-believe-what-happened-next`. All with the same rule. The page "name" will be mapped to parameter `page`. Then you treat parameter `page` like you would treat `id` (fetch page from database by it or whatever).

Comment: Wow, didn't know it can be done so easily. I'm very thankful :)